# Animation Not Playing (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a valid animation called `diceAnimation` from a valid `TextureAtlas` called `dice` that has several frames in it. What I have an issue with is rendering it. I use the code below to render the animation but it only shows the first frame. If I set `timeElapsed` to add one every time instead of using the delta time, it animates but REALLY FAST, ignoring the frames per second defined in the construction. Anyone have ideas?

```
int elapsedTime;

@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    dice = new TextureAtlas("textures/dice/dice.atlas");
    diceAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.033f, dice.findRegions("one"), PlayMode.LOOP);
}

// ...

@Override
public void render () {
    elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(diceAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 100, 100);
    batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data type of int `elapsedTime` should be float instead of int.

---

**OFF_TOPIC**

`PlayMode.LOOP` is  `PlayMode` of diceAnimation so you can use

```
batch.draw(diceAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime), 100, 100);
```